# Need to filter Informix database data by time interval (10 sec, 1Min, 2 Min 10 Min,1Hour, 6Hour)

Tags: database, informix

I have one table in my Informix 12.10 database which is currently log in with 10-second frequency.
My requirement is to retrieve data from that table in between Start Date and End Date with time interval (10 sec, 1Min, 2 Min 10 Min,1Hour, 6Hour).
Please help me to find a way.

Comment: on the internet, I found one SQL query for the 1-minute interval. below I am adding.please help me to translate this query into informix 12.10

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Date_Time, Tag1_Value, Tag2_Value, Tag3_Value, Tag4_Value
  FROM (SELECT DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, Date_Time), 0) AS Date_Time
             , Tag1_Value, Tag2_Value, Tag3_Value, Tag4_Value
         FROM ProDataTable
        WHERE Date_Time BETWEEN '2017-11-17 19:05' AND '2017-11-21 19:23') AS a
GROUP BY Date_Time, Tag1_Value, Tag2_Value, Tag3_Value, Tag4_Value
ORDER BY Date_Time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages. Also read the [tag:sql] information about how to ask an SQL question.  You've included the tag for the correct DBMS, which is good, but you've not shown an outline schema or any sample data and the expected output from that data.  Frankly, I'm not clear what you want — there are multiple ways of interpreting it. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ As a "for instance", suppose the start date is 2021-03-13 and the end date is 2021-03-14.  Should there be data for 24 hours or 48 hours in the output?  Is the time interval 2021-03-13T00:00:00 .. 2021-03-14T00:00:00, or 2021-03-13T00:00:00.. 2021-03-15T00:00:00 (excluding the end time points)?  When you use a large granularity like 6 hours, should there be an aggregate value such as AVG or MIN or MAX of the data, or should it be one value from within the range, and does it matter which value?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Date & Time we can select whatever Duration. My current date & time format is like this 2021-05-14 11:00:00. I require only one value from that range. suppose my start time is 2021-05-14 11:00:00 with an interval 0f 6 hours.so the next record should be 2021-05-14 17:00:00 and the column value should be close to 2021-05-14 17:00:00.